NgRX Store - init with Login (or Logout)
I can define my NgRxSignalStore with something like
export const MyStore = signalStore(
    { providedIn: 'root' },
    withState(initialValues4Store),
    withMySignalState(),
        ....


export function withMySignalState() {
    return signalStoreFeature(
        withState(additionalStates),

which is fine when I want to have the store application wide - just one instance.
What I'm not clear how to achieve a clear reset to the "initalValues" when the user logs out (or logs in). I know that I can create a method logout in MyStore and reset the values. Nevertheless the problem remains that I need to reset the values as well for the signalStoreFeature
Is there a way to inject an instance globally AND run an Injector manually which creates a new instance after the user has logged out?
EDIT
Just as a sidenote: I've tried as well something like
constructor(injector:Injector){...}
doLogout(): {
  injector.get(MyStore);
}

But this did NOT reinitalize the store.

If i understand correctly:
You want to reset the store and the state feature to there initial values?
You can add to your StoreFeature a Reset() method that will set the state to it's initial values
export function withMySignalState() {
return signalStoreFeature(
    withState(additionalStates),
    WithMethods(store=>({
    reset():void{
      patchState(store,additonalStates);
    }
    }))


And in the store just
export const MyStore = signalStore(
{ providedIn: 'root' },
withState(initialValues4Store),
withMySignalState(),
WithMethods(()=>({
resetStore():void{
 patchState(store,initialValues4Store);
 reset()://comes from the store feature
}
}))

